# How to apply a resolver to multiple routes

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a route config with multiple routes, and each route has the same resolver, except for the redirect. I would like a tidier way to apply the resolver to all of these routes but the redirect.

I've come across a solution to a similar question to this on StackOverflow before, but I could not find it for the life of me. This question may not be identical, as the redirect route would not have the resolver applied.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'contest',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'contest',
    component: ContestPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    resolve: DelayResolver,
  },
  {
    path: 'rules',
    component: RulesPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    resolve: DelayResolver,
  },
  {
    path: 'experience',
    component: ExperiencePageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    resolve: DelayResolver,
  },
  {
    path: 'enter',
    component: EnterPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    resolve: DelayResolver,
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    resolve: DelayResolver,
  },

];
```

Comment: There is no way, really, other than having them all as a child of a parent route, then applying the guard to the parent

Answer (score 0):

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContestWrapperComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'contest',
        component: AboutPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'rules',
        component: RulesPageComponent,
      },
     {
        path: 'experience',
        component: ExperiencePageComponent,
      },
     {
        path: 'enter',
        component: EnterPageComponent,
      },
     {
        path: 'about',
        component: ExperiencePageComponent,
      }

    ],
   resolve:DelayResolver
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent route that has no component.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'contest',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: '',
        resolve: {
            Data: DataResolver
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'contest',
                component: ContestPageComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full',
                resolve: DelayResolver,
            },
            {
                path: 'rules',
                component: RulesPageComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full',
                resolve: DelayResolver,
            },
            {
                path: 'experience',
                component: ExperiencePageComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full',
                resolve: DelayResolver,
            },
            {
                path: 'enter',
                component: EnterPageComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full',
                resolve: DelayResolver,
            },
            {
                path: 'about',
                component: AboutPageComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full',
                resolve: DelayResolver,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm not sure if the redirect should come before or after the empty parent, but if it doesn't work. Try moving the redirect to the bottom.

Comment: Cool. Would this add another route segment?

Comment: They don't add to the route segments, but they are greedy when matching the route. You might have to move the redirect as a child or to the bottom to get it to work. Now that I think of it. It might have to be the first child.